# Keep track of __add__'ed instances

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

I have a very simple Python class

```
class Component(object):
   pass
```

and two derived classes

```
class Planet(Component):
   pass

class Noise(Component):
   pass
```

I want to implement the `__add__` method of the `Component` class, such that I can do

```
a = Planet() + Noise()
```

But I don't know how to later access the two instances of `Planet` and `Noise` from within `a`.
In other words, I actually managed to implement `__add__` such that `a.c1` and `a.c2` were the two instances. But I don't know how to generalize that to

```
a = Planet() + Noise() + Noise()
```

Comment: But what would the result of such an addition be?

Comment: If I'm thinking correctly, it would have to be an instance of `Component`